# how to select from table with those condition?

Tags: mysql

the table  has  4  columns  follows :

```
id       int(11) not null  primary key,
name     varchar   not null ,
status   tinyint(1)  not null,
created  datetime not null
```

now,  I want to find out the result rows with conditions :

1. the  status  is  0;
2. foreach the result rows as A, if the table can select a row name B that  has the same `name` and `created` is the same day  and  `status` is 1,  except the A.

could  someone select  the result with  a sql without nested  select,  thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not entirely sure what your requirement is , but have you tried self joins?

Comment: @digjack - So, if you have condition "the status is 0", then how will be in second condition "status is 1" ?

Comment: I'm not sure who voted to close this question as "too broad" i.e. "too many possible answers or good answers will be too long". It's an anti-join. There is no other "good" answer. Okay, so there's a whole lot of possible *wrong* answers. But that doesn't make the question "too broad", C'mon. (If we're going to close the question it should be because it's a duplicate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an anti-join pattern fits the bill. This pattern requires *two* references to the table, but only a single SELECT keyword. As an example:

```
 SELECT t.id
      , t.name
      , t.status
      , t.created 
   FROM the_table t
     -- anti-join exclude matching rows
   LEFT
   JOIN the_table d
     ON d.name = t.name
    AND d.status = 1
    AND d.created >= DATE(t.created)
    AND d.created <  DATE(t.created) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
  WHERE d.name IS NOT NULL 
    AND t.status = 0
```

The trick is the outer join, to return all rows from `t`, along with matching rows from `d`, with the condition in the WHERE clause that *excludes* all rows that had a match. Leaving only rows from `t` that didn't have a matching row from `d`.

Answer (score 0):

`name` not in rows that has second condition:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename as o
WHERE o.status = 0
  AND o.name NOT IN
   (
    SELECT `name` FROM tablename as i
    WHERE i.status = 1
      AND i.created
          BETWEEN DATE(t.created)
              AND DATE(t.created) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select a.id,a.name,a.created,a.status from
(select b.id,a.name,b.created,b.status from 
(select count(name) as cnt, name from tbl_sample as a GROUP BY name) as a
LEFT JOIN
(select * from  tbl_sample) as b
on   a.`name` = b.`name`  where cnt>1 and STATUS = 0) as a

LEFT JOIN


(select b.id,b.name,b.created,b.status from 
(select count(created) as cnt, created from tbl_sample as a GROUP BY created) as a
LEFT JOIN
(select * from  tbl_sample) as b
on   a.`created` = b.`created`  where cnt>1 and STATUS = 0) as b
on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: This will return a result of status = 0 with (same name  and same created)in a row

Comment: This may return the specified result, but I count seven occurrences of the SELECT keyword. Part of the OP requirement specified: "without nested select".

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.status, a.created 
FROM userTable as a 
LEFT JOIN userTable as b 
ON a.name = b.name 
AND b.status = 1 
AND b.created BETWEEN DATE(a.created) AND DATE(DATE_ADD(a.created, INTERVAL 1 day))  
WHERE a.status = 0 
AND a.name IS NULL;
```

thanks the answer from @spencer7597 , I find out the result.

Comment: One note about the `b.created BETWEEN`  That's doing a "less than or equal to" comparison on the upper bound. The upper bound is midnight of the *next* day. The normal pattern is to do a "less than" comparison to the earliest time of the *next* day, not a "less than *or equal to*" comparison.